# Generalization of Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

For approximating realistic structures that mimic fractal, no-where differentiable manifolds, I'd like to say that such continuous boundaries in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be approximated by a series of polynomials. But, the Weierstrass approximation theorem is only for a 1-D case. How can it be generalized?

Comment: The Stone-Weierstrass works for families of functioned defined on a compact Hausdorff space (not necessarily a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ that separate points. I don't know the specifics problem you are dealing though.

Comment: For compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, any real valued continuous function can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial (in $n$ variables).